# Callback function for storing JSON to a variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a previous question where I was having issues for getting json from an url and storing it to a variable in order to pass it further to a function. I managed to get redirected to a solution that seemed promising, but it's still giving me undefined. The proposal was to use a callback as follows, but it doesn't seem to do the job.

```
var space = "";
function spaceCallback(data) {
  fplan = data.space['space'];
}
function getSpace() {
  var url = "http://localhost:8000/spaces/send_space/"
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
    spaceCallback(data);
  });
}
```

I would need to pass `space` to `blueprint3d.model.loadSerialized(space);`.

What am I missing here?

Comment: `console.log` `data` in `spaceCallback()`

Comment: That outputs the json I would like to pass to `blueprint3d.model.loadSerialized(space);`

Comment: @Daniel Please put a `console.log(data)` inside your $.getJSON callback. It seems your server is not able to send JSON formatted data. Please check.

Comment: i meant what @Tethys0 is saying, seems your server is not returning anything, adding a `console.log` in `spaceCallback()` to check whether the value is reaching the function

Answer (score -1):

Is it possible that you need to return your function?

```
function getSpace() {
  var url = "http://localhost:8000/spaces/send_space/"
  $.getJSON(url, function (data) {
   return spaceCallback(data);
  });
}
```

or ES6:

```
function getSpace() {
  var url = "http://localhost:8000/spaces/send_space/"
  $.getJSON(url, (data) => spaceCallback(data));
}
```

Comment: No. jQuery will ignore the return value of the success callback function.